# Error while trying to build a Latex project in VS Code

Tags: errors, latexmk

I hope that this is the right place for this question. I am a total beginner in latex. I am trying to make a latex file with notes for my college class and today when I tried to build a latex project I encountered an error that says:

```
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on c:/Users\Korisnik\Downloads\Analiza1zap.log.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'c:/Users/Korisnik/Downloads/Analiza1zap.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Examining 'c:/Users/Korisnik/Downloads/Analiza1zap.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

I understand that latexmk cant access the transcript? I tried to make a new file and it has the same problem no matter where it's saved on my computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It might be better to list the actual log. To me it seems there is an error in the compilation and pdflatex cannot proceed. We also don't know exactly which options `latexmk` is running `pdflatex` with. I'd probably start by eliminating VS Code completely and see if you can compile your document on the command line with a simple `latexmk -pdf file.tex` (for whatever name your doc have)

Comment: @daleif I did that on a new file and it did this                                                 
Output written on Untitled-1.dvi (1 page, 3388 bytes).
Transcript written on Untitled-1.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Untitled-1.dvi'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets

Comment: First of normal pdflatex does not generate dvi files. Did you remember to use the `-pdf`  otherwise run pdflatex directly. As mentioned please show the contents of the generated log file